# how to get last 7 activities per user

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

anybody can help me with some queries?

so i'm trying to see users behaviour in the month. i was trying to get all of their data sorting by userid but bigquery says:

> Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Peak usage: 107% of limit. Top memory consumer(s): ORDER BY operations: 100% .

thus i was thinking of only getting the last 10 activities of the user.
for example i have:

```
UserID        timestamp
123           28-Nov-2018
123           28-Nov-2018
123           28-Nov-2018
123           28-Nov-2018
123           27-Nov-2018
123           26-Nov-2018
123           20-Nov-2018
123           08-Nov-2018
123           08-Nov-2018
123           07-Nov-2018
123           05-Nov-2018
123           03-Nov-2018
234           28-Nov-2018
234           26-Nov-2018
234           25-Nov-2018
234           24-Nov-2018
234           24-Nov-2018
```

thus the result would be :

```
 UserID        timestamp
 123           28-Nov-2018
 123           28-Nov-2018
 123           28-Nov-2018
 123           28-Nov-2018
 123           27-Nov-2018
 123           26-Nov-2018
 123           20-Nov-2018
 123           08-Nov-2018
 123           08-Nov-2018
 123           07-Nov-2018
 234           28-Nov-2018
 234           26-Nov-2018
 234           25-Nov-2018
 234           24-Nov-2018
 234           24-Nov-2018
```

i should be getting only the last 10 activities of user 123 while capturing all activities of user 234 because its activity is less than 10

Comment: Please show your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> last 7 activities per user

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and should address Resources exceeded error which usually associated with using ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() with ORDER BY type of functions

Note: based on your example, I assume data type of your timestamp column is actually STRING, so I am using PARSE_DATE() function to cast it to DATE type

```
#standardSQL
SELECT UserID, ts FROM (
  SELECT UserID, ARRAY_AGG(ts ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', ts) DESC LIMIT 7) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY UserID
), UNNEST(arr) ts
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in your question:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 123 UserID, '28-Nov-2018' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '28-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '28-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '28-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '27-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '26-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '20-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '08-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '08-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '07-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '05-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 123, '03-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 234, '28-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 234, '26-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 234, '25-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 234, '24-Nov-2018' UNION ALL
  SELECT 234, '24-Nov-2018' 
)
SELECT UserID, ts FROM (
  SELECT UserID, ARRAY_AGG(ts ORDER BY PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', ts) DESC LIMIT 7) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY UserID
), UNNEST(arr) ts
ORDER BY UserID, PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y', ts) DESC
```

with result

```
Row UserID  ts   
1   123     28-Nov-2018  
2   123     28-Nov-2018  
3   123     28-Nov-2018  
4   123     28-Nov-2018  
5   123     27-Nov-2018  
6   123     26-Nov-2018  
7   123     20-Nov-2018  
8   234     28-Nov-2018  
9   234     26-Nov-2018  
10  234     25-Nov-2018  
11  234     24-Nov-2018  
12  234     24-Nov-2018
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work indeed :

```
        create table d061_userid (userid number,tt date);
        //do inserts 
        select * from d061_userid;
123 28-NOV-18
123 28-NOV-18
123 28-NOV-18
123 28-NOV-18
123 27-NOV-18
123 20-NOV-18
123 08-NOV-18
123 08-NOV-18
123 07-NOV-18
123 05-NOV-18
123 03-NOV-18
234 28-NOV-18
234 26-NOV-18
234 25-NOV-18
234 24-NOV-18

  select a.userID,a.tt from (select userID, tt,
  row_number() over (partition by userID order by tt desc) rank
  from d061_userid
  ) a where rank<=7 ;


    output:
123 28-NOV-18
123 28-NOV-18
123 28-NOV-18
123 28-NOV-18
123 27-NOV-18
123 20-NOV-18
123 08-NOV-18
234 28-NOV-18
234 26-NOV-18
234 25-NOV-18
234 24-NOV-18
234 24-NOV-18
```